New Firefox ... too much white space in left margin?
Just accepted installation of new version 125.0.2.
The ideal of any FF upgrade is that nothing new should be noticeable. However, I notice what appears to be irksome excessive white space in the left margin of many pages.
NB this is a VERY large monitor, 43 inches. This screen shot of a page at StackOverflow is taking up about half the screen (right half). It's not only StackExchange pages... I notice it quite a bit on other sites.
Anyone got any idea if there are any tweaks or anything which might work to reduce this silly white space?
PS come to think of it, the right margin is looking a bit too much too...


That looks about right. The Stackoverflow designers decided to not make the central column with the Q&A any wider so the individual lines of text are most readable. I have my browser window on full width and the lines of that particular post break at roughly the same words, and there is a huge amount of white space to the left and right. Maybe your Firefox upgrade changed the way some CSS rules were interpreted.

Thanks for the comparison and info re SO. Sometimes it'd be nice to be able to click back quickly to the previous FF version to see whether things were in fact pretty much the same!
